# In MVC How to pass a parameter to tabStrip when I was using Partial Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

In my view page, I have a button. When I click the button, I want to make the window open. The window  has some tabstrips, and in the tabstrip I want to show a grid and pass a parameter to the grid. Does kendo UI allow me to do this?

**Kendo Window**--**How to pass a parameter to the _TabStrip from my main view?(like the parameter is  "paraA" string)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("About Alvar Aalto")
    .Content(@Html.Partial("_TabStrip").ToHtmlString())
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(600)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
    .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose"))
```

)

**_TabStrip** (Partial View) **--How to pass a para from _TabStrip  to _Grid?(like the parameter is "paraA" string from main view)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("tabstrip")
.SelectedIndex(0)
.Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("Paris")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("_Weather").ToHtmlString());
        items.Add()
            .Text("New York")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("_Grid").ToHtmlString());
    })    
)
```

**_Weather** (Partial View)

```
 <div class="weather">
     <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
     <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
  </div>
 <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
```

**_Grid** **(Partial View)--How to get the parameter from _tabStrip?(like the parameter is "paraA" string from main view)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         .Refresh(true)
         .PageSizes(true)
         .ButtonCount(5))
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid").Data("GetParaFromMainView"))
        )
   )
 //How to get the parameter from main View 
 function GetParaFromMainView(){

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter. But it will require some changes in your views. In the same way you pass the model from the controller it is the same.
I will just write the lines who need to be changed or added.

### Main View

This line to open the window:

```
.Content(@Html.Partial("_TabStrip").ToHtmlString())
```

To:

```
.Content(@Html.Partial("_TabStrip",paraA).ToHtmlString())
```

### _TabStrip

In your `_TabStrip.cshtml` view you need to add the model in the top:

```
@model System.String //or just string
```

...
And change this line:

```
.Content(@Html.Partial("_Grid").ToHtmlString());
```

To

```
.Content(@Html.Partial("_Grid",Model).ToHtmlString());
```

### _Grid

And in your `_Grid.cshtml` add to the top too the model

```
@model System.String // or just string
```

And  change this line:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid").Data("GetParaFromMainView"))
    )
```

To

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid").Data(Model))
    )
```

I hopeit will help youto solve your problem. Use of an overload of `@Html.Partial` to pass the model whichis your cas a string. Have a try a let me know.

Comment: If I want to pass a 
dynamic parameter,How to fix it?For example,I want to pass "paraA",using
`.Content(@Html.Partial("_TabStrip",paraA).ToHtmlString())`,When I clike the button,I want to pass "paraB"?How to do that?

Comment: @lyly I don't get what you are saying. Does it work for a string? Now you want to pass a dynamic parameter? You can create a viewmodel class with properties `paraA` and `paraB` and you just the viewmodel

Comment: .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid").Data(Model)) seems wrong