# How to read a string parameter passed to a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Sorry if this appears as a duplication - I can see dozens of similar questions concerning Controllers, but not partial views inside views.

I have a very simple partial view:

```
<p>
   <input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
</p>
```

I then reference this across many views:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialView.cshtml")
```

Suppose I need to change the `value` of the button in the partial view.  I think I can reference the partial view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialView.cshtml", new { ButtonValueParam = "Restart" })
```

But then how to I read the value of `ButtonValueParam`?  I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<p>
   <input type="button" value="@ButtonValueParam " onclick="history.go(-1);" />
</p>
```

All other examples I've seen today either include a Model or a Controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597927/in-mvc-how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-tabstrip-when-i-was-using-partial-views

Comment: @ViewData.ButtonValueParam?

Comment: A full code sample would be appreciated please. I don't have the experience to wade through dozens of lines of code and unrelated logic to find the bit I need

Answer (score 0):

You can pass with the help of `ViewDataDictionary`.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyPartialView.cshtml", new { new ViewDataDictionary { "ButtonValueParam", "Restart" }} )
```

and read the values from the `ViewData`.

```
<input type="button" value="@ViewData["ButtonValueParam"]" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @karthik.  On MSDN ViewDataDictionary is described as *... a container that is used to pass data between a controller and a view*.  Is this the de-facto way to achieve this (no alternatives), as there's no Controller being used?

Comment: First line gives a compiler error **Syntax error, ',' expected**. `new { ViewDataDictionary {` should be `new ViewDataDictionary { {` I believe?

Comment: That gives **Invalid anonymous type member declarator**.  I leave it as `new ViewDataDictionary { {` as that's working, unless you know that's not right...?!